# Remove sendmail from listening on port 25?

Tags: email, postfix, sendmail

I have tried and tried to remove sendmail (using debian) but it seems to not be gone.  It is still listening on port 25, and I don't want it to be:

```
zedsaid:/etc/rc2.d# lsof -i :25
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
sendmail- 23925 root    3u  IPv4 4535835       TCP zedsaid.com:smtp (LISTEN)
```

I have done apt-get remove sendmail and also manually removed some things, but it won't go away.  I need to have postfix listening to port 25 instead, is there a way to manually remove sendmail from listening on port 25?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kill any remaining sendmail processes.

```
pkill sendmail
```